# Get items using spsitedata query

Tags: spsitedataquery

I'm using `SPSiteData` query to fetch the list items from different list as you can see below:

```
 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
             SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
    query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"105\" />";
    query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"FirstName\" Nullable=\"TRUE\" Type=\"Text\"/>";
    query.Query = "<OrderBy>" + 
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" + 
                           "</OrderBy>";
    query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";
```

Now after applying the `spsitedata` query, i want to cast the items in `SplistItemCollection`. Like this, how we use to do for single list.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["List1"];
            SPListItemCollection queryResults = list.GetItems(query);
```

How can i achieve this ? Any kind of help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: The result of a `SPSiteDataQuery` can not be cast to an `SPListItemCollection`

Comment: is there any way where i can cast them ?

Answer (score 0):

SPSiteDataQuery returns result in DataTable. and then you have to manipulate results.
if you want to get listitemcollection then you have to loop through all webs in sitecollection using spquery and merge the results.